# Java instance variables set to 0

Tags: java

I'm new to understand Java, so forgive me for my ignorance. I have compiled the following code:

```
import java.lang.Math;
public class Main{
  double initialBalance;
  double interestRate;
  double years;


  public static final double periodsPerYear = 12;

//constructer
  public Main(double balance, double interest, double life){
    }

//methods
  double getMonthlyPayment(){
    return Math.round(initialBalance * ((interestRate/periodsPerYear)+((interestRate/periodsPerYear)/(Math.pow(1+(interestRate/periodsPerYear),periodsPerYear*years)-1)))*100.00)/100.00;
  }


//main method
  public static void main(String[] args){
    double initialBalance = 10000;
    double interestRate = 0.05;
    double years = 2;

    Main loan = new Main( initialBalance, interestRate, years );
    System.out.println(initialBalance);
    System.out.println(interestRate);
    System.out.println(years);
    System.out.println(loan.getMonthlyPayment());
  }
}
```

The problem is the line "System.out.println(loan.getMonthlyPayment())" returns 0.0 when I need to to return 438.71. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately - this lets those with knowledge of the language you need help with to see your question.

Comment: its a java not a javascript

Comment: You do not assign any values to the instance variables `initialBalance` etc.

Comment: advice: add some lines like `initialBalance = balance;` to constructor  - so the fields are initialized (otherwise they hold the default value: zero)

Answer (score 1):

In your initialization of the object:

```
Main loan = new Main(initialBalance, interestRate, years);
```

this constructor is called:

```
public Main(double balance, double interest, double life){
}
```

but it doesn't do anything. It's empty. You need to set the instance variables in the constructor, like so:

```
public Main(double balance, double interest, double life){
  this.initialBalance = balance;
  this.interestRate = interest;
  this.years = life;
}
```